# Build a class with a Timer object

Tags: vb.net, class

Good afternoon.
I wanted to ask you if it is possible (and if you can!!??) to build a class in VB.NET (use VS2012) with a timer-like object that when instantiated starts the timer (in new() ) and at set time intervals exposes a certain event.
The available TIMER object can only be entered on forms, but I didn't want to handle a form but define a class and then instantiate its objects from time to time. I hope I've explained myself.
Thank you for any helpful advice.

Comment: Yes this is definitely possible.  SO is probably better for answering more specific programming questions rather than broad concepts like '`How to I do this thing?`'.

Comment: You can easily find some helpful pages and even YouTube videos by doing a Google search for something like: `create timer vb.net form`. Good luck with your efforts

Comment: What exactly can't you do? Create the timer, Starting it under the Class constructor or what exactly? Please update your question to include the necessary information.

Comment: I would like to create the timer, Starting it under the Class constructor!!